# Django. Автоматический вызов метода при обращении к модели

Tags: python, django

В проекте на Django, есть обычная модель со своими полями и методами, где данные привязаны к конкретному пользователю, ничего необычного. Появилась необходимость сделать так, чтобы через определённый промежуток времени одно из полей обновляло свои данные по формуле. Для примера возьмём поле rank(рейтинг), которое должно каждые 3 часа увеличиваться, скажем на 100. Так как нет явной необходимости, чтобы в БД всегда находились самые свежие данные, решил не делать обновление пока нет вывода на экран этих данных. Для большего понимания: если надо провести какие-то манипуляции с данными при сохранении, то, можно переопределить метод save. А как сделать подобное при запросе типа "select"?

Comment: По-моему, проще и правильнее сделать всё-таки нормальное обновление каждые три часа по крону

Comment: У меня эти 3 часа не совсем статичные, а для каждого пользователя они разные. Зависит от времени регистрации. Для одного пользователя может быть в 18:53:56, а для второго в 18:54:32

Comment: Тогда, может, лучше эти данные вообще не хранить, а просто считать заново каждый раз при необходимости?)

Comment: Может и так, хотя терзают меня смутные сомнения в этом плане. :) Но так или иначе, теперь уже интересен сам вопрос, как это можно сделать. :)

Comment: Можно попробовать  создать для модели [Custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) и в нем перед тем как вернуть queryset сделать необходимые вычисления.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никогда не редактируйте объекты неявно! За изменение базы при обычном select я бы больно побил. При select все нормальные люди ожидают, что данные будут лишь получены, а не изменены.

Можно создать метод, вызов которого будет пересчитывать рейтинг и из названия которого будет чётко видно, что данные будут обновлены:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class User(models.Model):
    # ... всякие другие поля ...
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    registered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # при регистрации здесь ставим дату регистрации плюс 3 часа (в UTC)
    next_rank_update_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def update_and_get_rank_value(self, save=True):
        changed = False

        # Алгоритм подсчёта рейтинга можно оптимизировать, но мне лень
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        while self.next_rank_update_at <= now:
            self.rank += 100
            self.next_rank_update_at += timedelta(hours=3)
            changed = True

        if changed and save:
            self.save()

        return self.rank
```

Тогда в шаблонах можно выводить рейтинг примерно так:

```
<b>Рейтинг пользователя: {{ user.update_and_get_rank_value }}</b>
```

Когда вывода на экран нет, метод никем не вызывается, и рейтинг в базе будет старый. Когда вывод понадобится, будет вызван метод из шаблона, рейтинг пересчитается и данные в базе обновятся — всё как вы хотели :)

Или, как я предложил в комментариях, можно вообще не хранить рейтинг, а каждый раз считать его заново:

```
from datetime import datetime

class User(models.Model):
    registered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_rank_value(self):
        delta = datetime.utcnow() - self.registered_at
        return delta.total_seconds() // 3600 // 3 * 100
```

Comment: Не надо меня больно бить, я знаю дзен пайтон. :) И про неявность тоже не говорил, просто, хотелось во views одно строкой всё делать, вместо select->update->select. Честно говоря, посмотрев на ваш ответ, понял, что вопрос изначально был глуповат и мог сам к нему дойти. Спасибо за труды, очень помогли.